# CakePHP slug converting my Bangla text to English

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-4.x

I am trying to save category name after convert in slug

So in entity I have used setter for convert my text to slug text

```
protected function _setName($name)
{
    return Text::slug($name);
}
```

After send post request in input name `"আমি তোমায় ভালোবাসি"`
Has got in database

```
ami-tomaya-bhalobasi
```

After make transliteratorId false

```
return Text::slug($name,[
   'transliteratorId' => false
]);
```

I got output : আম-ত-ম-য-ভ-ল-ব-স

My expected result is

```
আমি-তোমায়-ভালোবাসি
```

How can I get my desire result ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole point of slugs is to obtain a "safe" pure US-ASCII string. If all you seemingly want is to remove white spaces you can use a simple regular expression:

```
preg_replace('/\s/u', '-', 'আমি তোমায় ভালোবাসি')
```

However, I recommend you double-check why you think this is necessary in the first place. A properly encoded URL would display spaces as `%20` anyway, which is "ugly" in a Latin script text but will get unnoticed in other scripts:

```
var_dump(rawurlencode('আমি তোমায় ভালোবাসি'));
```

```
string(159) "%E0%A6%86%E0%A6%AE%E0%A6%BF%20%E0%A6%A4%E0%A7%8B%E0%A6%AE%E0%A6%BE%E0%A6%AF%E0%A6%BC%20%E0%A6%AD%E0%A6%BE%E0%A6%B2%E0%A7%8B%E0%A6%AC%E0%A6%BE%E0%A6%B8%E0%A6%BF"
```

Comment: For some Japanese text example  "a3!（エースリー）", preg_replace are not replacing , do you have any idea about that ?

Comment: That text doesn't have any space at all: https://apps.timwhitlock.info/unicode/inspect?s=a3%21%EF%BC%88%E3%82%A8%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B9%E3%83%AA%E3%83%BC%EF%BC%89